# APScheduler ValueError: The target callable does not accept the following keyword arguments:

Tags: python, python-3.x, apscheduler

I am running into an error calling add_job with kwargs for a function:

I created a function to create scheduled jobs:

```
def initial_data_pull():
    q.enqueue(initial_pull, timout='3h')


def initial_data_load():
    dates_list = date_between_list(start=date(2010, 1, 1), stop=date.today())
    naics = ['541611', '541618', '541613',
             '541511', '541512', '541513',
             '541519', '518210', '541612']
    fundings = ['3600', '97DH', '7504', '7505',
                '7522', '7523', '7524', '7526',
                '7527', '7528', '7529', '7530',
                '7570']
    for date_item in dates_list:
        for fund in fundings:
            for naic in naics:
                sched.add_job(initial_data_pull,
                              kwargs={'naics_code': naic,
                                      'funding_agency_id': fund,
                                      'date_signed': date_item})
```

The function `initial_pull` looks like:

```
def initial_pull(naics_code=None, funding_agency_id=None, date_signed=None):
    print('Gathering Contracts...')
    df = fpds_generic(naics_code=naics_code,
                      funding_agency_id=funding_agency_id,
                      date_signed=date_signed)
    # Code to Process and load data
```

The function `fpds_generic` is a function that goes to fpds and gather's data.  I am getting the following error when I run the `inital_data_load` function.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clock.py", line 55, in <module>
    initial_data_load()
  File "clock.py", line 52, in initial_data_load
    sched.add_job(initil_data_pull, kwargs=kw)
  File "/home/spitfiredd/anaconda3/envs/g2x_flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 425, in add_job
    job = Job(self, **job_kwargs)
  File "/home/spitfiredd/anaconda3/envs/g2x_flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 44, in __init__
    self._modify(id=id or uuid4().hex, **kwargs)
  File "/home/spitfiredd/anaconda3/envs/g2x_flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 175, in _modify
    check_callable_args(func, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/spitfiredd/anaconda3/envs/g2x_flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apscheduler/util.py", line 385, in check_callable_args
    ', '.join(unmatched_kwargs))
ValueError: The target callable does not accept the following keyword arguments: naics_code, funding_agency_id, date_signed
```

Why is it saying that the function does not accept those keyword args when it does, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Theres an inconsistency here. You seem to pass a callable named `initil_data_pull` but you show us a callable `inital_data_pull`. Verify this isn't a simple typo issue and ammend your question if that isn't the case.

Comment: I just updated the code, there was no type in my code, only a type in my question because I was leaving out part of my code.

Comment: Well, the initial callble you pass doesn't accept *any* keyword argument. Define it using `**kwargs`, i.e `def initial_data_pull(**kwargs): ...`. That seems to be the issue (Haven't worked with APScheduler so I'm mainly going with my intuition)

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Ahh I see where I went wrong.  Thank you.